# Show that orthogonal matrices have eigenvalues with magnitude $1$ without a sesquilinear inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, alternative-proof

Is it possible to consider complex eigenvalues without a Hermitian (i.e. sesquilinear) inner product over a complex vector space?

---

For instance: let $A$ be a real orthogonal matrix (so $A^TA = I$).  Without referencing a Hermitian inner product, is it possible to show that the complex eigenvalues of $A$ have magnitude $1$?

The usual proof of this fact is as follows: if $x,\lambda$ is an eigenpair of $A$, then we have
$$
\|x\|^2 = x^*x = x^*(A^*A)x = (Ax)^*(Ax) = \lambda\overline{\lambda} (x^*x) = |\lambda|^2 \|x\|^2
$$
from which it follows that $|\lambda| = 1$.  Note: this proof required the use of the sesquilinear inner product $\langle x,y \rangle = y^*x$.

---

A rephrasing of the original question: consider $\Bbb C^n$ with the bilinear from 
$$
\langle x,y \rangle = y^Tx
$$
note that this bilinear form is **not** an inner product. The complex-orthogonal matrices are those matrices $A$ that satisfy $A^TA = I$, where $T$ is the entrywise transpose.  Notably, the complex-orthogonal matrices preserve the above bilinear form.  How can we show that if $A$ is complex-orthogonal with real entries, then the eigenvalues of $A$ have magnitude $1$?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but are you allowed to reference to a symmetric bilinear *real* inner product on $\Bbb R^n$? Or are you looking for something that flat-out uses only the structure of real vector space + $\overline {\Bbb R}=\Bbb C$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli sure, can't see why not.  The question I'm avoiding is how this bilinear form should extend to the complexification of the vector space.

Comment: Do you mean the conjugate transpose by $A^T$ ?

Comment: @Astyx well in this context, $A$ is a real matrix, so of course the two are the same.

Comment: So are we in a real vector space then  ? In any case if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $X$ an associated eigenvector, we have $|\lambda|^2 X^*X = X^*A^TAX = X^*X$ which leads to $|\lambda|^2 = 1$ (since $X\ne0$)

Comment: I guess the question is whether I can talk about complex eigenvalues without saying what an inner product (or transpose) does to complex vectors (or matrices).

Comment: In finite dimension there is a canonical inner product associated to each vector space (since all $\Bbb F$ -vector spaces of dimension $n$ are isomorphic). So you do not need to explicitly say there is an inner product in your vector space in order to use it.

Comment: Is it true for orthogonal matrices with not-necessarily-real entries too?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval it is not!  See my [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290362/on-eigenvalues-of-complex-orthogonal-matrices/2290490#2290490)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, still your very first question's answer is that of Arthur.. The explanations below the line don't represent this question. Add the power $^2$ to $\|x\|$  in your equation. Otherwise I think you would agree that the property of the eigenvalues norm actually follows from the matrix being orthogonal and surely can be proven without explicitly talking about complex inner product. But all proofs would be, in essence, equivalent.

Comment: @Veliko *"I think you would agree that the property of the eigenvalues norm actually follows from the matrix being orthogonal and surely can be proven without explicitly talking about complex inner product"*.   I'm not so sure, hence the question.  The transpose property of orthogonal matrices is ultimately a reference to a real inner product, hence the issue.

Comment: @Astyx it does *not* always make sense to put an inner product on a vector space.  For instance, if $\Bbb F$ is a finite field, then there is no inner product.  $\Bbb C$ is not ordered, so there is no bilinear inner product; but we exploit the fact that $\Bbb R$ is an ordered subfield.  Also, inner products don't make sense on many normed vector spaces.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I meant $\Bbb F =\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, I should have pointed that out, my bad

Comment: @Astyx sure.  I guess my main issue, in any case, is that the definition of a complex vector space does not say anything about a sesquilinear inner product, and such an inner product is **not** required to define real orthogonal matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in a way, yes. The real Jordan normal form theorem yields that every real matrix has an invariant subspace $W$ (i.e. $AW\subseteq W$) such that $1\le\dim W\le 2$. Since $\dim W^\perp +\dim W=n$ and, if $A$ is orthogonal, the orthogonal complement of an $A$-invariant subspace is $A$-invariant, there is an orthonormal basis $B=(b^1,\cdots, b^n)$ such that $B^{-1}AB=B^TAB=\begin{pmatrix}U &0\\ 0&U'\end{pmatrix}$, for some $U\in O(2)$ and $U'\in O(n-2)$ - or, repsectively, $O(1)$ and $O(n-1)$. Now, the eigenvalues of $A$ are either eigenvalues of $U$ or eigenvalues of $U'$. The form and eigenvalues of a $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrix can be calculated explicitly, and the rest can be done by induction.

That being said, as far as I know the real Jordan normal form theorem is proved by complexifying the endomorphism of $A$, using the machinery of Jordan normal form in $\Bbb C^n$, and then bringing it back to $\Bbb R^n$. So one could argue that this is just hiding the issue under the carpet.

Comment: Interesting approach!  I agree that the real Jordan form trick is sweeping *something* under the rug... but I think all that can be framed in terms of polynomials, perhaps.

Comment: Seems legit to me. The usual machinery involved in the Jordan theorem does not use anything Hermitian.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I've just seen the part where you state the actual problem. I don't know how to tackle it on top of my head and, for now, I don't know if this approach may work effectively: last time I tackled a similar problem, I thought exactly the thing I wrote and took a grizzling blunder.

Comment: Uh oh.  Still, it's the closest thing  that I'll get to an answer quickly.  If I really try to tackle it, maybe I'll ask a follow up.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I mean, it can certainly be used to prove that $A^TA=I$ and $A$ real implies that the eigenvalues of $A$ are roots of unity. However, I suggest caution with generalizations: I once tried to craft a proof of $A\in O(n,m)\implies A\text{ diagonalizable in }\Bbb C$ and I ended up using it incorrectly (for the obvious reason that it was a false theorem).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli aha.  Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an argument without using the sesquilinear inner product on $\mathbb C^n$, but the usual bilinear inner product $b$ on $\mathbb R^n$ is still used. Essentially:

1. By using the normality of $Q$ with respect to the real inner product $b$, it can be shown that, up to a change of orthonormal basis on $\mathbb R^n$, we may assume that $Q=(-I_s)\oplus R$ for some real orthogonal matrix $R$ that doesn't possess $-1$ in its spectrum.
2. By using Rayleigh quotients on $\mathbb R^n$ (and so we are still using the real inner product $b$), it can be shown, [without stepping into the complex field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1124875), that every real symmetric matrix has a real orthonormal eigenbasis. It follows that every real positive semidefinite matrix has a complete and nonnegative spectrum.
3. By [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Matrix_map), $R=(I-K)(I+K)^{-1}$ for some real skew-symmetric matrix $K$. As $-K^2=K^TK$ is positive semidefinite, all complex eigenvalues of $K$ are purely imaginary (this is straightforward if we can use the sesquilinear inner product on $\mathbb C^n$; since we cannot use it here, we need item 2). Since $|(1-z)/(1+z)|=1$ for every $z\in i\mathbb R$, we conclude that all eigenvalues of $R$ lie on the unit circle.

Comment: Very nice. The first two steps seem natural but using the Cayley transform is clever.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a notion of complex scaling (which you have by definition of "vector space over $\Bbb C$"), you can define eigenvalues and eigenvectors. You cannot, without a norm or inner product, say anything about normalised eigenvectors, or whether the eigenvectors are orthogonal, or anything like that, but the *eigenvalues* are just complex numbers. As such they behave as complex numbers always do, which specifically means that they have an absolute value / norm of their own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Just so you know, I've narrowed the question down quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can show this in a way which seems to me more elementary than the answers above suggest. The key is simply that if $A \in \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb R)$ satisfies $A^tA$ then $A$ is an isometry of $\mathbb R^n$ (with respect to the usual Euclidean distance). Since $A$ has to preserve the length of a vector, and in particular any eigenvector, its real eigenvalues must lie in $\{\pm 1\}$.

For the complex eigenvalues of $A$, we have to consider $A$ as a linear map on $\mathbb C^n$, but as a real vector space this is just $\mathbb R^n \oplus i\mathbb R^n$, with $A$ acting "diagonally'', that is, $A(v_1+iv_2) = Av_1+iAv_2$. By imposing the condition that the two copies of $\mathbb R^n$ are orthogonal to each other, and using the usual dot product on each copy, $\mathbb C^n = \mathbb R^n \oplus i\mathbb R^n$ naturally inherits a (real) inner product from $\mathbb R^n$, and the diagonal action of $A$ still preserves distances.

Now if $\lambda=\lambda_1+i\lambda_2\in \mathbb C$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ thought of as an operator on $\mathbb C^n$, then we may find an eigenvector $v=v_1 +iv_2$ for $A$ with this eigenvalue. Now
$$
\begin{split}
A(v_1+iv_2) = (\lambda_1 + i\lambda_2)(v_1+iv_2) = (\lambda_1 v_1 -\lambda_2v_2)+ i(\lambda_2v_1 +\lambda_1v_2)
\end{split}
$$
and thus we must have $A(v_1) = \lambda_1 v_1-\lambda_2v_2$ and $A(v_2) = \lambda_2v_1 + \lambda_1 v_2$, and since $A$ is an isometry $\|A(v_1+iv_2)\| =1$, hence
$$
\begin{split}
\|v\|^2 &=\|v_1\|^2+\|v_2\|^2 = \|A(v_1)\|^2+\|A(v_2\|^2 \\
&= \lambda_1^2\|v_1\|^2 +\lambda_2^2\|v_2\|^2 -2\lambda_1\lambda_2\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle \|v_1\|^2 \\
& \quad + \lambda_2^2\|v_1\|^2 +\lambda_1^2\|v_2\|^2 +2\lambda_1\lambda_2\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle \|v_1\|^2 \\
&= (\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2)(\|v_1\|^2+\|v_2\|^2) = (\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2)\|v\|^2
\end{split}
$$
Thus $|\lambda|^2=1$ as desired.